# Is there a difference between StringDictionary class and Dictionary<String,String>

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, collections

System.Collections.Specialized contains StringDictionary
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringdictionary.aspx#Y1626

What's difference with Strong Typed Dictionary in Generics?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`StringDictionary` comes from .Net 1, which predates generics.

Therefore, unlike `Dictionary<String, String>`, it doesn't implement any generic interfaces, so it cannot be used with LINQ (unless you `Cast()`)

Also, `StringDictionary` normalizes all keys to lowercase.
(To make a case-insensitive `Dictionary<String, String>`, pass `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`; this is also more compatible with Turkey)